# Playing Diablo 3 behind a proxy?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I tried changing the "Internet Options" for the computer but it only seems to work on the launcher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using **Widecap** http://www.widecap.com/ - it's freeware and works fine, not just with games, but with all kind of network software

or

**Proxifier** http://www.proxifier.com/ - I play many game through it. Everything is ok.

You could also choose one of other proxifiers
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers

Comment: i've used widecap to direct traffic through my own SSH tunnel I set up with Putty, but how would one use it to play Diablo 3 when your network uses a proxy?

Comment: Widecap could redirect traffic for all (or specified) programs through that network proxy and doesn't count what you have in "Internet Options"

Comment: I've been reading the Battlenet forums and it appears to me that I can be banned completely from the game. How can I use this safely?